# Return String of Characters Repeated x Times

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, repeat

**Can someone please help me with this function.**

char *repeat(char *s, int x)

Returns a new string consisting of the characters in s repeated x times. For example, if s is the string all right , the function returns the new string all right all right all right. If s is NULL, the function returns NULL.

It is up to the caller to free any memory allocated by the function.

**This is what I have so far...**

char *repeat(char *s, int x){

```
int i;
int count = 0;

while(s[count] != '\0')
{
    count++;
}

int repeat = count * x;
char *newArray = malloc(5000);

for(i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
{   
    while(*s != '\0')
        *newArray++ = *s++;     
}

return (char*)newArray;
```

}

Comment: `*newArray++ = *s++;` : don't change `newArray` and reset `s` each for-loop. and `newArray` need null-terminate. and needs more code for  `NULL` case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *repeat(const char *s, int x){
    if(s){
        int i, count = 0;

        while(s[count] != '\0'){
            ++count;
        }

        char *newArray = malloc(count * x + 1);
        if(newArray){
            char *na = newArray;
            for(i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
                const char *p=s;
                while(*p)
                    *na++ = *p++;
            }
            *na = '\0';
        }
        return newArray;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue--assuming you're only getting one copy back--is that you need to "reset" the pointer `s` between your copies.  Right now, you hit the end of `s`, so the successive iterations are trying to copy a string of `"\0"`.

Two potential other problems (for the future) are:

- You should be using (I'm guessing you know this one and aren't allowed to do otherwise) `strcpy()` to do the copying.
- Memory should always be allocated by the function's caller.  The pointer to the new string goes on the call stack and the memory goes on the heap technically assigned to `repeat()`, so when you return, the run-time is under no obligation to preserve any of it for the caller to use.  It "usually works," but it can be painfully dangerous.

Answer (score -2):

First allocate memory then copy/move the memory.
For your reference, a simple one(not fully test):

```
char *repeat(char *s, int x)
{
    char *result = malloc(sizeof(s) * x + 1);

    while (x > 0) {
        strcat(result, s);
        x --;
    }

    return result;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    char *sample = "hell";
    char *result = repeat(sample, 3);


    printf("result : %s\n", result);

    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

You'd better:

1. don't forget `x` should be the integer and  greater than 0;
2. always remember to  `free` the created string

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I'm not allowed to use functions from string.h in this function. This is my first ever class in C and I'm finding pointers a bit confusing.